# woocommerce to fetch grouped products "Parent" for the child product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to have a section to display the parent product for those linked child product. So user can know where to go back to the grouped product.

However I cannot know how the query should work. The below code fetches all the parent product, and I only want to display the one linked to the child.

```
<?php
function repeater_dynamic_query( $query ) {
  global $post;
  if ( $query->query['post_type'][0] == 'product' ) {
    $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                                array(
                                  'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                                  'field' => 'slug', 
                                  'terms' => grouped                               
                                )
                              ) );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array($post->ID) );
    $query->set( 'no_found_rows', true );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'repeater_dynamic_query' );
?>
```

I found function from the woo doc, but it seems to be expired. Not sure if this could help. Thanks

get_parent()

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product-Grouped.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I got my someone who managed to solve my problem. For those who may need this.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'no_found_rows' => 1,
        'meta_query' => [ 
            array(
                'key' => '_children',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                'value' => get_the_ID()
            ),
        ]
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        print_r($query);
    }
});
```